# Find occurrences in a list of files and count them

Tags: grep, find

I have a large set of thread dumps which are in a directory tree (one folder for each 30 minutes).

I'm trying to count how many Threads are in a single file.
So far I've come up with:

```
find . -name 'high-cpu-tdump.out' -exec grep -H "Thread-" {} \;
```

This returns :

```
./cbsmtjfuprd2/2021.10.22-06.30/high-cpu-tdump.out:"Thread-0 (HornetQ-server-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=7582b137-83b1-11e9-bc0d-b5863efb47a2-961209098)" #123 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f01a45be000 nid=0x4a4 waiting on condition [0x00007f010b730000]
./cbsmtjfuprd2/2021.10.22-06.30/high-cpu-tdump.out:"Thread-1 (HornetQ-scheduled-threads-2107959528)" #121 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f01c01ff800 nid=0x4a2 waiting on condition [0x00007f0130897000]
./cbsmtjfuprd2/2021.10.22-06.30/high-cpu-tdump.out:"Thread-0 (HornetQ-Asynchronous-Persistent-Writes221963927-1847608919)" #120 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f01a4527000 nid=0x49a waiting on condition [0x00007f0131487000]
./cbsmtjfuprd2/2021.10.22-06.30/high-cpu-tdump.out:"Thread-0 (HornetQ-scheduled-threads-2107959528)" #116 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f01a4377800 nid=0x490 waiting on condition [0x00007f0131ce4000]
. . . . . .
```

That's a good start, however I need to chain it with a 'wc -l' so that I know for each file how many Threads are in.
I'm doing some attempts but all are failing:

```
find . -name 'high-cpu-tdump.out' -exec grep -H "Thread-" {} | wc -l \;
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Do you have an idea if that it's doable with find or do I have to write a script which checks dir by dir each single file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pipe `wc -l` to the `grep` command as part of `-exec` without using an explicit shell invocation with `sh -c` i.e.

```bsh
find  . -name 'high-cpu-tdump.out' -exec sh -c 'grep -H "Thread-" {} | wc -l' ';'
```

But running this does *not* produce the filenames, in which the patterns are found. To reliably do this, suggest using a shell loop inside `sh -c` that does the printing of filename and associated word count

```bsh
find . -name 'high-cpu-tdump.out' -exec sh -c '
    for file; do printf "%s %s\n" "file" $(grep -c "Thread-" "$file") ; done' -- {} +
```

Or use `grep` alone without find, making use of the `--include` flag (GNU/BSD variants) that allows to provide a glob expression to search only those files while recursing

```bsh
grep -r -c 'Thread-' --include='high-cpu-tdump.out' .
```

---

I would suggest also using [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) which greps for file recursively by default and is much faster ([source](https://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/)). In which you could just do

```bsh
rg -c 'Thread-' -g 'high-cpu-tdump.out'
```

Comment: Thanks I have tried the grep solution and it worked like a charm!

Comment: While not just `find ... -exec grep -Hc pattern {} +`? Note that `-H`, `-r` and `--include` are all GNU extensions.